# Uploading Images from Expo app to local server in typescript

Tags: typescript, post, expo, multipartform-data, dataform

I'm working on an upload and fetch images app using Expo, node.js and Typescript.

I created my own local server where images are uploaded using Multer and URL is stored in mongo dB using mongoose.

**server upload code (tested it using postman and it's working)**

```
pp.use(morgan('dev')); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/images',express.static('images'));
app.use('/images', router);

router.post('/', fileUpload.single('image'), (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    const image = new imgModel({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        path: req.file?.filename
    });
    image.save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));

    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'posting all images!!'
    });
});
```

**In the Expo app I don't know how to send the data after fetching it from local library, this is my code so far but it's not working (Expo is running on local Emulator)**

```
const SERVER_URL: string = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000';
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result :ImagePicker.ImagePickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1
    });

    console.log(result)
    if (result.cancelled) {
      return
    }
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('image',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( {
      uri: result.uri,
      type: 'image/jpg', 
      name: 'testPhotoName'
    })));

    let options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    };
    fetch(`${SERVER_URL}/images`,options)
  };
```

This is the result I'm getting back from the image picker :

```
{"assetId": "36", "base64": null, "cancelled": false, "exif": null, "height": 1280, "type": "image", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ImagePicker/145371a3-54b8-46f4-add6-254e216238df.jpeg", "width": 960}
```

I took the code from an article where they implement the form data like this:

```
    data.append('photo', {
      name: photo.fileName,
      type: photo.type,
      uri: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? photo.uri.replace('file://', '') : photo.uri,
    });
```

but I get this error (presumably because I'm using typescript) :

> Argument of type '{ name: any; type: any; uri: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'Blob'.

I found this issue online and changed it to:

```
    data.append('image',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( {
      uri: result.uri,
      type: 'image/jpg', 
      name: 'testPhotoName'
    })));
```

But it's stil not working I'm getting

> MulterError: Unexpected field

is there a fix for this or is there another way to send the images and retrieve it?

(Side note: I'm new to js, node.js, ts, and React Native) so if you can please provide the documentation for any suggestion or solution would be appreciated)